# ImageView error

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-drawable

I faced with a really strange problem. This occurs only if I set a drawable as src to ImageView.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.backgrounds.test/com.backgrounds.test.activities.PointsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #76: Binary XML file line #76: Error inflating class ImageView
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #76: Binary XML file line #76: Error inflating class ImageView
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #76: Error inflating class ImageView
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.at.d()' on a null object reference
at android.support.v7.widget.au.setImageDrawable(Unknown Source:5)
```

This error is not occurring if I don't set any drawable to this ImageView.

I tried to change drawables, compress them, re-import to project but nothing helped me. Can someone help me?

Comment: Add xml part and point out the line . Also point out the OS version you are testing in right now.

Comment: @ADM... You are everywhere

Comment: May be you are adding your images in `drawable-v24`... but you have to add images in `drawable` too..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also facing same problem, and solving by addding below line in your
 **Activity's onCreate() method:**

```
AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
```

**and also try with adding in ImageView of your xml file:**

```
app:srcCompact instead of android:src.
```

Its work for me.Please try it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your error is at inflating imageView .Please  check your your imageView not null before set image src.